# bunch of radio buttons and want to enable the toggle on one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a vanilla `javascript` on radio buttons to show/hide the block of tr with id to select of a radio and on the `unselect` of the radio, hide that piece..

the vanilla js is working fine, want to move to jquery to tryng to the same in jquery but i am bit lost here

so every radio has different ID attached to it with no class. and i only want to show the radio of id10 if checked , if any other radio is selected, i want to hide that div, how can i do in `jquery`

for javascript i am doing this

```
function toggle() {
              var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
              if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
              } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
              }
            }
```

tried like this :

but its not even doing anything

not even an alert

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#myDiv").hide();
                $('input[name="outputFormat"]').click(function() {
                    alert("hi");
                    let id = $(this).attr('id');
                    if(id == 'of9') {
                        $("#myDiv").show();
                    }else {
                        $("#myDiv").hide();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Do you include jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the radios by using an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with the desired group name. Then you can use [`.is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/) to check if the current element matches your selector (like [`Element.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) in vanilla) and then toggle the visibility with the utility functions [`.show()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.hide`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/).

```js
$('input[name="sel"]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is('#id10')) {
    $('#myDiv').show();
  } else {
    $('#myDiv').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="sel" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="sel" value="2" id="id10">
<input type="radio" name="sel" value="3">

<div id="myDiv">Content</div>
```